# Low-momentum behaviour of a short-range potential

Tags: momentum, schroedinger-equation, potential

I've read the follow sentence in a [journal article](http://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-th/9706029v1) (arXiv preprint) which constitutes part of my coursework.

> As discussed in the previous section, the low-momentum behavior of any short-range potential is efficiently described in terms of the Taylor expansion in momentum space.

It would really help me out if you could explain what is meant here. I am a fourth year physics undergraduate with a basic knowledge of quantum mechanics, so you might have to dumb down a bit.

Comment: Could you include a link/reference to the article where you read that?

Comment: Yes. Here's the link: http://arxiv.org/pdf/nucl-th/9706029v1.pdf  The sentence is in the final paragraph of page 9.